# Wipe android emulator before every ui test suite run on Build Machine

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, android-espresso, fastlane

Right now when I run the integration test suite on the Build Machine,Emulator on Build Machine gets slow and subsequent builds will fail. In order to solve this, I have to manually go and wipe the emulator and restart it again. Is there a way to automate this using Fastlane or anything else?

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line to your app's `build.gradle` to reset the state of the app in between test runs:

```
testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
```

I believe this is most effective when added to the following:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
    
    }
}
```